# Getting Textmate to recognize Ruby version upgrade

Tags: ruby, version, textmate

I used the instructions at http://bparanj.blogspot.com/2010/06/installing-ruby-191-on-snow-leopard.html to install Ruby version 1.92 on my Mac running Snow Leopard.  The only deviation is in step 3, which calls for .bash_profile to be updated.  I have .profile, but not .bash_profile, in my home directory, so I added the export command to the last line of .profile. The installation completed successfully (with the same two warning messages as mentioned, which I too disregarded), as Ruby -v in a terminal prints

```
ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-07-02 revision 28524) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0].
```

When I run Textmate, however, cntrl-R invokes Ruby version 1.8.7, as it did before the 1.9.2 installation.  In Textmate's Preferences-Advanced-Shell Variables, TM_RUBY is set to /usr/bin/ruby. The (binary alias) file 'ruby' has not been updated. What is the easiest way for me to instruct Textmate to use the newer version of Ruby?  Please note my understanding of OS X is relatively limited.

Comment: Put this in `~/.profile`: `alias ruby=/opt/local/bin/ruby`

Comment: Thanks, Adrian. I first tried Brian's suggestion, as it worked, I didn't look farther.

Comment: @Adrian, not sure that would have solved @Cary's issue (running 1.9.2 as TM_RUBY from Textmate).  Adding path variable to .profile (under the bash shell) is perfectly fine (albeit the last place bash looks for configuration information upon initialization).  Reference:  http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the easiest way for me to
>   instruct Ruby to use the newer version
>   of Ruby?

I believe you mean "What is the easiest way for me to instruct Textmate to use the newer version of Ruby?"

Assuming that is the case, have you tried to edit the TM_RUBY shell variable to point to your newly installed version?  According to the docs you referenced, it should be somewhere under /usr/local (most likely /usr/local/bin/ruby).

You can find out the location of your ruby installation by typing the following in your terminal window:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
```

then perform the following to verify the version

```
$ ruby -v
```

Once you have the proper ruby path, in Textmate,  double-click the 'value' of the TM_RUBY shell variable & type in the path to your 1.9.2 install.

Comment: Thanks, Brian. 'which ruby' gave me the same past as in your post, and changing the value of TM_RUBY to that path fixed my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just create a .bash_profile file in your home directory?